# Knockout.js sort list

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I had a sorted list using knockout.js for a select list. I want to convert it for an unordered list. What is the method for sorting a list with knockout.js? I am thinking the error is with: allItems().length > 1

http://jsfiddle.net/infatti/Ky5DK/

```
var BetterListModel = function () {
    this.allItems = ko.observableArray([
        { name: 'Denise' },
        { name: 'Charles' },
        { name: 'Bert' }
    ]); // Initial items

    this.sortItems = function() {
        this.allItems.sort();
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new BetterListModel());


<button data-bind="click: sortItems, enable: allItems().length > 1">Sort</button>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
this.allItems(this.allItems().sort(function(a, b) { return a.name > b.name;}));
```

Comment: Can you please edit you answer for ascending and descending sorting? I am confused what are a and b?

Comment: 'a' and 'b' are not variables that you use in your application, those are actually some random variables from sort function, because sort functions needs to receive 2 parameters for sorting 2 items, right? :)

Comment: It's generally accepted on SO that you explain your code sample and not just provide a copy and paste answer.  This helps future users who arrive here looking for more information about this topic.

Answer (score 7):

```
var BetterListModel = function () {
    this.allItems = ko.observableArray([
    { name: 'Denise' },
    { name: 'Charles' },
    { name: 'Bert' }
    ]); // Initial items

    this.sortItemsAscending = function() {
        this.allItems(this.allItems().sort(function(a, b) { return a.name > b.name;}));
    };

    this.sortItemsDescending = function() {
        this.allItems(this.allItems().sort(function(a, b) { return a.name < b.name;}));
    };
};
```

lines explained:
weWiliChangeTheArrayToValue(weWilSortTheArrayWithASpecialFunction(ComparatorFunction))

ComparatorFunction ie.

```
function(a, b) { return a.name < b.name;}
```

is a special function that helps the sort function to... well sort.
It takes 2 arguments and compares them returning true if first argument is 'bigger' (should be further away on the list) and false if the first argument is 'smaller'
Every (almost) sorting algorithm works by comparing 2 elements of sorted collection until all are in order.
 
Changing the order is done by making sure that the function returns false when it would return true normally - easiest way to do so is by changing the > operation to <

EDIT one more thing: if you compare non-ASCII characters use return a.localCompare(b); (and return b.localCompare(a);) and when dealing with numbers use "-" sing so it's an arithmetic operation

EDIT2
Warning the above method ">" might break with duplicates in array use

```
return a.name < b.name ? -1 : a.name > b.name ? 1 : 0;
```

instead (or just localCompare)

Comment: This should be marked the correct answer.  It answers the question and explains what is going on in the code sample. +1